# After Docker push container is not assuming changes

Tags: docker

For context i initially built a docker image where, besides other stuff i added, i created a user and a group with UID 2001.
Later on i had to change the UID to match the Host OS to UID 6670.
The steps were
1\ Pushed first image (uid 2001) to our development DTR with version:2.5.3
2\ Updated Dockerfile with UID 6670 and built new image with version:2.5.3 (to overwrite the previous one)
3\ When running the container the UID of the user was still 2001
4\ Since it seemed it was not updating the image correctly i retagged the image to version:2.4.3
5\ When running the container the UID of the user was 6670 as expected

You can check the imageId on our DTR that is the same one. (check the attached image)
Can you help me figure out why, if i try to overwrite the image with the same version number it's not taking the changes into account?   I guess its picking up the first version i pushed.
This is only happening if i push it with a new version number.

[dtr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APQTF.png)

To add extra information. When building this in our pipeline we can see it's pulling different images id's despite the current image id in DTR being the same (see below an excerpt from jenkins log)

```
Step 1/6 : FROM dtrdev.xxx.com/xxx/app1:2.5.3
---> 91da87758939
```

```
Step 1/6 : FROM dtrdev.xxx.com/xxx/app1:2.4.3
 ---> fafdd771aef6
```

Comment: Did you explicitly `docker pull` the image on the target system?  It's usually a good practice to use a unique tag per build to avoid this class of problem.  (And it's not usually best practice to encode details of a specific host in an image – I guess I can't use your image since `id -u` says my user ID is 501 on this system.)

Comment: yes, its included in mine CI/CD pipeline.  
Yeah, i the different versions i understand. Since i'm preparing a "base image" to be used with this specific version i needed to "fix" this UID issue